# Why can't I call methods in fragment's onCreateView?

Tags: android, android-fragments

This is my first time dealing with fragments so I don't know how to operate with them that well yet. I have a fragment in which I have onCreateView method. In that onCreateView method I have code that populates custom listview from SQLite database:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_library, container, false);

    Log.i("TAG", "onCreateView");

    // Variables
    lView = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.listView);
    components = new ArrayList<RecordDetails>();
    db = new DatabaseHandler(getActivity());
    Cursor c = db.getAllRecordedFiles();

    if(c.moveToFirst()){
        element = new RecordDetails();
        element.setTitle(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(SQLiteHelper.MUSIC_NAME)));
        element.setDate(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(SQLiteHelper.MUSIC_DATE)));
        element.setDuration(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(SQLiteHelper.MUSIC_DURATION)));
        components.add(element);

        while (c.moveToNext())
        {
            element = new RecordDetails();
            element.setTitle(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(SQLiteHelper.MUSIC_NAME)));
            element.setDate(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(SQLiteHelper.MUSIC_DATE)));
            element.setDuration(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(SQLiteHelper.MUSIC_DURATION)));
            components.add(element);
        }

        lView.setAdapter(new CustomListViewAdapter(components, getActivity()));
    }

    return v;
}
```

This works fine. Now let's say I want to put the code for populating listview into method and **then** call that method in onCreateView like this:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_library, container, false);

    Log.i("TAG", "onCreateView");

    // Variables
    lView = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.listView);
    components = new ArrayList<RecordDetails>();
    db = new DatabaseHandler(getActivity());
    Cursor c = db.getAllRecordedFiles();

    populateListView();

    return v;
}

public void populateListView(){
    if(c.moveToFirst()){
        element = new RecordDetails();
        element.setTitle(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(SQLiteHelper.MUSIC_NAME)));
        element.setDate(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(SQLiteHelper.MUSIC_DATE)));
        element.setDuration(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(SQLiteHelper.MUSIC_DURATION)));
        components.add(element);

        while (c.moveToNext())
        {
            element = new RecordDetails();
            element.setTitle(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(SQLiteHelper.MUSIC_NAME)));
            element.setDate(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(SQLiteHelper.MUSIC_DATE)));
            element.setDuration(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(SQLiteHelper.MUSIC_DURATION)));
            components.add(element);
        }

        lView.setAdapter(new CustomListViewAdapter(components, getActivity()));
    }
}
```

And when I do this, the app crashes with the following LogCat output:

```
02-20 20:57:17.505: E/AndroidRuntime(4675): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-20 20:57:17.505: E/AndroidRuntime(4675): java.lang.NullPointerException
02-20 20:57:17.505: E/AndroidRuntime(4675):     at com.matejhacin.beautifulvoicerecorder.LibraryFragment.populateListView(LibraryFragment.java:70)
02-20 20:57:17.505: E/AndroidRuntime(4675):     at com.matejhacin.beautifulvoicerecorder.LibraryFragment.onCreateView(LibraryFragment.java:64)
02-20 20:57:17.505: E/AndroidRuntime(4675):     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1500)
02-20 20:57:17.505: E/AndroidRuntime(4675):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:927)
02-20 20:57:17.505: E/AndroidRuntime(4675):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1104)
02-20 20:57:17.505: E/AndroidRuntime(4675):     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
02-20 20:57:17.505: E/AndroidRuntime(4675):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1467)
02-20 20:57:17.505: E/AndroidRuntime(4675):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:472)
02-20 20:57:17.505: E/AndroidRuntime(4675):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:141)
02-20 20:57:17.505: E/AndroidRuntime(4675):     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1068)
02-20 20:57:17.505: E/AndroidRuntime(4675):     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:914)
02-20 20:57:17.505: E/AndroidRuntime(4675):     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1436)
02-20 20:57:17.505: E/AndroidRuntime(4675):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15855)
02-20 20:57:17.505: E/AndroidRuntime(4675):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5012)
02-20 20:57:17.505: E/AndroidRuntime(4675):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
02-20 20:57:17.505: E/AndroidRuntime(4675):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15855)
02-20 20:57:17.505: E/AndroidRuntime(4675):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5012)
02-20 20:57:17.505: E/AndroidRuntime(4675):     at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:302)
02-20 20:57:17.505: E/AndroidRuntime(4675):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15855)
02-20 20:57:17.505: E/AndroidRuntime(4675):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5012)
02-20 20:57:17.505: E/AndroidRuntime(4675):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
02-20 20:57:17.505: E/AndroidRuntime(4675):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2451)
02-20 20:57:17.505: E/AndroidRuntime(4675):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15855)
02-20 20:57:17.505: E/AndroidRuntime(4675):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1905)
02-20 20:57:17.505: E/AndroidRuntime(4675):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1104)
02-20 20:57:17.505: E/AndroidRuntime(4675):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1284)
02-20 20:57:17.505: E/AndroidRuntime(4675):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1004)
02-20 20:57:17.505: E/AndroidRuntime(4675):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5481)
02-20 20:57:17.505: E/AndroidRuntime(4675):     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:749)
02-20 20:57:17.505: E/AndroidRuntime(4675):     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:562)
02-20 20:57:17.505: E/AndroidRuntime(4675):     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:532)
02-20 20:57:17.505: E/AndroidRuntime(4675):     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:735)
02-20 20:57:17.505: E/AndroidRuntime(4675):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
02-20 20:57:17.505: E/AndroidRuntime(4675):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
02-20 20:57:17.505: E/AndroidRuntime(4675):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-20 20:57:17.505: E/AndroidRuntime(4675):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5289)
02-20 20:57:17.505: E/AndroidRuntime(4675):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-20 20:57:17.505: E/AndroidRuntime(4675):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
02-20 20:57:17.505: E/AndroidRuntime(4675):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:739)
02-20 20:57:17.505: E/AndroidRuntime(4675):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:555)
02-20 20:57:17.505: E/AndroidRuntime(4675):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

So I'm guessing that Fragments act differently when calling methods. What should I do?

Comment: As developers, we should care about accuracy.  Java does not have functions.  You've written a method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `Cursor c` class member and the local one you create inside `onCreateView` are different objects, and redeclaring a local variable you are "hiding" the class member.

you can change

```
Cursor c = db.getAllRecordedFiles();
```

with

```
c = db.getAllRecordedFiles();
```

or you can add a parameter to populateListView passing the Cursor object

```
public void populateListView(Cursor c){
}
```

and call it from onCreateView like

```
 populateListView(db.getAllRecordedFiles());
```

Answer (score 2):

Your Cursor C is defined in the scope of `onCreateView()`. So you can't use it in `populateListView()`
You can do something like this.

```
private Cursor c;
```

now in onCreateView :

```
          c = db.getAllRecordedFiles();
```

Answer (score 0):

From the error I see that your method throws NPE due to Variable c is not declared as class member variable rather a local variable to onCreateView(). Please pass c as argument to populateListVIew() you should be good.